# Can't stop AVFoundation song

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm making a game with level selection in Swift 3.0, and I'm using AVFoundation to play background music. I'd like to play a different song for every level, however when I try to stop the song and play a new one after I've beaten the level, instead of stopping it it just replays it. Here's my code, seriously been working on this for hours and gotten no where.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class LevelSelect: UIViewController {
    var AudioPlayer0 = AVAudioPlayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let AssortedMusics0 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Background", ofType: "mp3")!)
        AudioPlayer0 = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: AssortedMusics0 as URL)
        AudioPlayer0.prepareToPlay()
        AudioPlayer0.numberOfLoops = -1
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    @IBAction func Level0Button(_ sender: Any) {
        AudioPlayer0.stop()
        AudioPlayer0.play()
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like when you call `play()` again, it's still set to play the `Background.mp3` file. You didn't set it to any other MP3 file. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, why do you get the path, convert that to an `NSURL`, and then convert *that* to a `URL`? That's needlessly convoluted. Just call `Bundle`'s `url(forResource:withExtension:)` to get the URL in one step.

Comment: The play() is irrelevant in the shortened code I supplied, the audio is just played over the past audio. As for the NSURL, I copy and pasted that because I am completely new to AVFoundation, so whatever is wrong with that I really have no clue.

Comment: From the code you posted, you stop the audio, and then you immediately go ahead and play the same audio again. Unless this isn't indicative of your actual code, of *course* it's still going to replay the same song.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it never actually stops playing the song, so the songs are overlapping each other.

Comment: It stops playing; it's just that it immediately starts playing again, since you call `play()` right after calling `stop()`. If you get rid of the `play()`, it will just stop.

Comment: Okay, what's happening is even when I remove the play(), the music continues to play after I leave the View Controller and return to it and press the button. If I have play() in it, it simply plays the song two times with different starting points, which sounds awful.

Comment: Never mind, still not sure why this is happening but I've decided to just put the audio in for each level's view controller. Thanks anyway though!